# Save data on Content Type programmatically

Tags: drupal-7

I just created a content type "Cars", How I can save data on "Cars" from form programmatically?

```
function form_tutorial_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    $title = $form_state['values']['title'];
    $body = $form_state['values']['body'];
    $field_color = $form_state['values']['field_color'];
    $nid = db_insert('cars')->fields(array(
        'title' => $title,
        'uid' => 1,
        'created' => REQUEST_TIME
    ))->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to save new node use following

```
function form_tutorial_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    $title = $form_state['values']['title'];
    $body = $form_state['values']['body'];
    $field_color = $form_state['values']['field_color'];
    $nid = db_insert('cars')->fields(array(
           'title' => $title,
           'uid' => 1,
           'created' => REQUEST_TIME
    ))->execute();

    // Save new node 
    $node = new stdClass();
    // Set node title
    $node->title = $title;
    // set node type ex: article etc
    $node->type = "YOUR_NODE_TYPE";
    // set node language
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    //(1 or 0): published or not
    $node->status = 1;
    //(1 or 0): promoted to front page
    $node->promote = 0; 
    $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = $body;
    $node->body['und'][0]['format'] = 'full_html';
    node_object_prepare($node);
    node_save($node);   
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: welcome ram, if like the ans please mark it as correct.